# Force trailing slash if the URL exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need some help to a particular **redirect in htaccess**. It's not a simple "*force trailing slash*".

So my problem is to redirect all URLs that don't have a trailing slash to a trailing slash. I accomplish this with this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|xml|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

but there is a big problem doing this: if i fire for an **URL that doesn't exists** and **doesn't have a trailing slash**, Apache fires a 404 error, but for the **URL that doesn't exists WITH TRAILING SLASH**. So initially is redirected **301**, then 404. This seems to make no sense.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test existence first (with [OR]) and not non-existence:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, now i'll test it but i've a question: how does this code will handle double slash in the URL? For example: `https://www.example.com////how-to////something-tutorial`    --> if i test it in htaccess tester (online) it will redirect to the homepage.. with single slash is working properly. How can i accomplish both (redirect multiple slash in url to one and force the final trailing slash). Thanks for your time

Comment: the first one rule is working perfectly but i cannot remove every slash in URL's path as said above. Why in your opinion? the second rule doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `^(.*?)//+(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]`